# CMAKE: Updating a list in a function does not work

Tags: cmake

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487215/cmake-function-parameter-and-return) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031953/how-to-set-the-global-variable-in-a-function-for-cmake) link to write a function that:

- takes a list of files as input,
- appends path to each file
- Creates a new list (passed as an output
  parameter to the function itself) by appending all the files to it

  ```
  function(concat_path iLiItems oLiItems cVal) 
    foreach(pfile ${${iLiItems}})
      string(CONCAT l ${${cVal}} ${pfile})
      message(STATUS ${pfile} " - " ${l})
      set(${oLiItems} ${${oLiItems}} ${l} PARENT_SCOPE)
    endforeach()
  endfunction()

  function(list_print liItems)
      message(STATUS "The list contains: ")
    foreach(f ${${liItems}})
      message(STATUS ${f})
    endforeach()
  endfunction()

  set(PROTO_SRCS base.proto dht.proto)

  foreach(pfile ${PROTO_SRCS}) 
    string(REPLACE ".proto" ".pb" fname ${pfile})
    string(CONCAT cc ${fname} ".cc")
    string(CONCAT h ${fname} ".h")
    set(PROTO_CPP_SRCS ${PROTO_CPP_SRCS} ${cc} ${h})
  endforeach()

  string(CONCAT path_prefix ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} "/")
  concat_path(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_SRCS_PATH path_prefix)
  list_print(PROTO_SRCS_PATH)
  ```

The problem I see is that when I finally print using the function, "list_print" i see that only one element is present in the output list (PROTO_SRCS_PATH) where as I was expecting two corresponding to both the input files:

```
-- base.proto - C:/Users/vaddina/workspace/protobuf-tests/app-wo-findprotobuf/base.proto
-- dht.proto - C:/Users/vaddina/workspace/protobuf-tests/app-wo-findprotobuf/dht.proto
-- The list contains:
-- C:/Users/vaddina/workspace/protobuf-tests/app-wo-findprotobuf/dht.proto
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With *PARENT_SCOPE* option you change value of variable in the parent scope, but a **variable in the current scope is unchanged**. This is explicitely descrbed in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/set.html#command:set) about *PARENT_SCOPE*:

> This command will set the value of a variable into the parent directory or calling function (whichever is applicable to the case at hand). **The previous state of the variable’s value stays the same in the current scope** (e.g., if it was undefined before, it is still undefined and if it had a value, it is still that value).

Because of that, the call to

```
set(${oLiItems} ${${oLiItems}} ${l} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

always see empty value as the second argument (you never assign the variable in the current scope). So the variable in the parent scope is always assigned (not appended!) by `${l}`.

Normally, setting a variable with PARENT_SCOPE is performed **only once**. Intermediate calculation should use and update variable in the current scope:

```
function(concat_path iLiItems oLiItems cVal) 
  foreach(pfile ${${iLiItems}})
    string(CONCAT l ${${cVal}} ${pfile})
    message(STATUS ${pfile} " - " ${l})
    set(${oLiItems} ${${oLiItems}} ${l}) # Update list in the current scope only
  endforeach()
  # Before return, propagate variable's value to the parent scope.
  set(${oLiItems} ${${oLiItems}} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved the Problem. I was indeed very tricky.